# Two carousels per row

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4 to make these two carousels appear side by side on my laptop screen (col-md-6) and full width on a mobile screen (col-sm-12). I'm not sure why this isn't working. Perhaps I'm trying to affect the wrong elements?

```
  <div id="col-md-6 col-sm-12 carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{homepage.homepage_image.url}}" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{homepage.homepage_image.url}}" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{homepage.homepage_image.url}}" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="col-md-6 col-sm-12 carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{homepage.homepage_image.url}}" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{homepage.homepage_image.url}}" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{homepage.homepage_image.url}}" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- row end -->
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing a `row` class, it goes like this.

the `row` first, then `col`, then what should be there

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    carousel-1
  </div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    carousel-2
  </div>
</div>
```

Check here:

https://jsfiddle.net/AbdulAzeez/a5g2x7de/6/][1]

And secondly, i don't know if you are getting error on image load. Why don't you use `src binding` either, using your preferred framework.